# Добавление элемента через события без использования id или класса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код:

```
function test(event) {
        $(this).after("aaa" + "<br>"); //в данном случае работает и выводит
        //текст сразу после элемента, на котором было инициировано событие
        //click
        $.post("/php/tasks.php", {
            taskname : "abc"
        }, function(req){
            //$(this).after("bbb" + "<br>");
            // почему не работает? в чем разница? ошибка -> TypeError: b is undefined
            var json = $.parseJSON(req);
            for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
                //$(this).after(json[i].f_name); //здесь выводится нужный мне
                //текст, который я получаю с сервера в виде json
            }
        });
    }
```

на странице есть несколько тегов

```
<p>...</p>
```

при клике на каждый на сервер идет определенный POST, после чего из него данные надо вставить под вызвавшим блоком. Почему отмеченная функция, до того как я выполняю POST, работает нужным мне образом, а внутри функции с ответом от сервера перестает и выдает ошибку? Как это исправить? Может быть, есть более хороший способ сделать то, что я описал?

P.S. id/class не используются т.к. количество элементов может быть любое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объект this в коллбеке post уже новый. `this` в обработчике события указывает на HTMLElement, на котором было поймано событие, а `this` в коллбеке - на jquery ajax объект:

```
$.post('example.com', function(){ console.log(this); });
```

Console:

```
accepts: Object
async: true
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
contents: Object
converters: Object
crossDomain: false
dataTypes: Array[2]
flatOptions: Object
global: true
hasContent: true
isLocal: false
jsonp: "callback"
jsonpCallback: ()
processData: true
responseFields: Object
success: ()
type: "POST"
url: "example.com"
xhr: Fn()
__proto__: Object
```

Так что вам нужно сохранить ссылку на объект и пользоваться ею в коллбеке:

```
function test(event) {
    var $el = $(this);

    $.post("/php/tasks.php", {
        taskname : "abc"
    }, function(req){
        var json = $.parseJSON(req);

        for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
            $el.after(json[i].f_name);
        }
    });
}
```

Другим способом обратиться к this из родительского скопа может быть использование [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), которые не имеют своего this объекта:

```
function test(event) {
    $.post("/php/tasks.php", {
        taskname : "abc"
    }, req => {
        let json = $.parseJSON(req);

        json.forEach({ f_name } => $(this).after(f_name));
    });
}
```

Но они работают нативно только в самых новых браузерах. Так что без [транспайлеров](https://babeljs.io) их лучше не использовать. Попробовать ES6 можно тут: http://www.es6fiddle.net/.